# Using element dataset as variable to dynamically call function

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I have an object that creates a 1:1 mapping between string values and functions like so.

```
var game_modules = {
  battleship: battleships_module,
  chess: chess_module
}
```

Where battleships_module and chess_module are individual functions that set up the event listeners and operations associated with a particular game. For example...

```
var battleships_module = function(){
   var game_container = document.getElementById("battle-ships-game-container");
   //Rest of game functionality here
}
```

Depending on which game the user clicks to play, each "click game" button is a tag that contains its module name as a data-* attribute. For example

```
<div id="battle-ships-button" class="play-game-button" data-game_module="battleship">   </div>
```

and I am trying to retrieve the data-game_module in javascript to get its value and dynamically call its associated module in the `game_modules` object we defined earlier by registering an event listener on "click" like so:

```
some_element.onclick = function(e) { //e is click event
  var clicked_element = e.target //clicked element
  var current_module = clicked_element.dataset.game_module //supposed to retrieve the clicked element's data-game_module tag

game_modules[current_module](); //supposed to run the associated function defined in game_modules



}
```

But this does not work. It only works if I define a string literal like...

```
var current_module = 'battleship';
game_modules[current_module](); //this works
```

I was wondering if anyone knows why dataset is being treated differently. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check what `console.log(current_module)` logs? And how can `game_modules[current_module]();` work, given that 'battleships_module' is not one of your object's keys?

Comment: It correctly outputs the name of the module which is why this is so puzzling

Comment: Oops that was a typo. The idea is the same that using a string literal works, but using a variable that is an element's data-* attribute does not work

Comment: Semicolons inside your object literal are a syntax error. You really need to work on posting a correct demo instead of a mishmash of unverified code.

Comment: Not having a comma inside your object literal is a syntax error. You really need to work on posting a ***correct*** demo instead of a mishmash of unverified code.

Comment: I made the adjustments. I'm sorry about any confusion it may have caused

Comment: You'll get the best help (and will save your helpers some time) if you follow this help center advice: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mean time you corrected the typos in the data attribute (battleship) and the object literal (no semi-colon, but comma), but to repeat:

- Make sure the spelling of the data attribute is exactly the same as the key of your `game_modules` object
- Check your console for syntax and run-time errors.

But also make sure that you:

- initialise the function variables `battleships_module` and `chess_module` *before* you reference them in your object `game_modules`; so the order should be opposite to what you posted in the question.
- bind the event listener to the HTML element that has the data attribute. Or, if you bind it to a parent, make sure to use `currentTarget` (assuming the element having the data attribute does not have children that can capture the click event).

Here is a short demo:

```js
var battleships_module = function(){
        console.log('battleships module chosen');
    },    
    chess_module = function(){
        console.log('chess module chosen');
    }    

var game_modules = {
    battleship: battleships_module,
    chess: chess_module
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.play-game-button'), function(div) {
    div.onclick = function(e) {
        var clicked_element = e.target;
        var current_module = clicked_element.dataset.game_module;
        game_modules[current_module]();
    };
});
```

```css
.play-game-button {
    border: 1px solid; 
    background: silver;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<div id="battle-ships-button" class="play-game-button" data-game_module="battleship">Chose Battleships</div>
<div id="chess-button" class="play-game-button" data-game_module="chess">Chose Chess</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am correctly referencing the correct key name. (the example in the question was a typo, but I had it correct in the project). It's just using element.dataset is not being treated like a string literal and I'm not sure why because console.log(typeof some_element.dataset.game_module) prints out "string"

Comment: I added a snippet to my answer which triggers the function, as you can see. Make sure you also initialise the variables in the correct order and that you bind the click listeners to the HTML elements that have the data attribute.

Comment: thank you so much for this!!! I got it working! I just realized that you were right and there was a mismatch between the key name and the data-* attribute. I used "battleships-module" in the dataset, but battleships_module inside the object function mapper